# facebook landing page with iframe to my own domain

Tags: facebook, iframe

Hello fellow developers.

I have previously made a facebook fan page with an iframe that link to a web page on my own server.

Now when I try to recreate this for a customer I am tearing my hair since facebook has changed everything around.

I have followed the steps in a "fresh" tutorial I found at http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-fall-2012/ and I have the web page on my server, but I can't figure out how I get the fan page to use my "app", in other words I can't figure out how to get the iframe into my fan page.

I have also checked out the http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196 but it is not really what I want. I prefer to have it all on my own domain since it's easier to update.

Please help. I need to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following URL: http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages=1

Be sure to replace **APP_ID** with your app ID.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I saved a few strands of hair. Where did you find this information?

Comment: I can't remember and can't find it in their docs. They seem a bit undecided as to how the correct protocol for this will be. Check out http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ where they talk about the new «Add to Page» dialog. Also, don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: They sure do. I honestly dont know how I would have made it without your help. Something so simple as providing a link so one can connect an app to a fan page, facebook sucks with all the changes and no up to date documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the web page on my server, but I can't figure out how I get the
>   fan page to use my "app", in other words I can't figure out how to get
>   the iframe into my fan page.

Hi, you will need to go to your apps profile page (https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id={your app id}).  In the left hand column there's a link saying "Add to My Page", select the page you want it added to from the list that pops up.  Voila! All done.